# How to write that a character waits a certain amount of time?

Tags: fiction, narrative, time-depiction

Let's say the character of the story has to wait a day and you need to write in the  story in a smooth manner that they waited the day for the thing they were expecting?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Jorge.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  We're glad to have you here.  Unfortunately, this is a question that's been asked before.  But please hang around and answer or ask other questions about writing.